# Why do we care about the 'rapidness' for convergence?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, infinity

It is those puzzeling improper integrals that I can't get my head around....

Does the (improper) integral $\frac 1{x^2}$ from 1 to $\infty$ coverges because it is converging "fast" or because it has converging anti-derivative? in case of the former, what do you mean by "fast"?

Likewise the integral $\frac 1x$ from $1$ to $\infty$ is divergent, it that because it does not appraoch the x-axis "fast enought"? Eventaully it does approach the x-axis as we take the limit as x $\to \infty$. For me it is more logical to say that is has an anti-derivative (namely, $\ln(x)$) that blows up as $x$ $\to \infty$

Which reasoning is correct and why?

Comment: Both are correct; "goes to zero fast" is shorthand for "has an antiderivative that doesn't grow to infinity". The latter is more precise, the former is easier to say, and leads to a way of talking about functions that tends to provide useful ideas for later rigorous proofs. There's another flavor of "improperness" that comes from integrals like $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x} dx$, where the integrand "blows up" at the limit of integration. People speak of the integrand "growing too fast at 1" as shorthand for a limit (of an expression involving the antiderivative) being infinite.

Comment: Well, "not convering fast" pretty much confused me that is has something to do with 'speed' so it was not very clear. Anyways thanks for your answer! @John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison tests (either [direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) or via a [limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)) are concrete, rigorous statements expressing the intuition behind the statement that 
$$\int_a^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$$
converges if $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ "fast enough".

The direct comparison test, for example, states that if $0\leq f(x)\leq g(x)$ and if
$$\int_a^{\infty} g(x) \, dx$$
converges then 
$$\int_a^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$$
must also converge.  Now, if $0\leq f(x) \leq g(x)$ then I think it's reasonable to say that $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ *at least as fast* as $g(x)$ so, again, this is one expression of your intuition.

Of course, one thing that's nice about the comparison test, is that we don't need to find an anti-derivative to apply it.  For example,
$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{8/3}(x)}{x^2}\,dx$$
converges by comparison with $1/x^2$, even though we'll probably never find a nice anti-derivative for the integrand.

It might be worth mentioning that we often compare to functions of the form $1/x^p$ and the $p$-test provides another expression of your statement.  That is,

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p} \, dx$$
converges if and only if $p>1$.  Furthermore, the larger $p$ is, the faster $1/x^p \rightarrow 0$ in a quantitative sense that can be made precise with inequalities.